# Filtering select field options in django-admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I am using [django-xadmin](https://github.com/sshwsfc/xadmin) for one of my project which is based on django-admin. I need help in a case. Suppose, i have two models like this -

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('a', 'Option A'),
        ('b', 'Option B')
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CHOICES)

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

In xadmin, when i try to add **Bar** via default form provided by xadmin, in the select Field **Foo**, all **Foos** (both with Option A and Option B) become available to select. I want to filter the options and only provide, say, **Foos** of **Option A**.

How can i do that ? Is there any method in xadmin, i should call or customize to achieve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to)

**EDIT**

Consider this example from the doc:

```
staff_member = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    limit_choices_to={'is_staff': True},
)
```

> causes the corresponding field on the ModelForm to list only Users
>   that have is_staff=True. This may be helpful in the Django admin.

Therefore, this is an easy way of adding restrictions on corresponding fields.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it. But you should add some explanation with your answer, not only a link.

Comment: I can if you need some, but I didn't want to be repetitive. The doc, in this case, is really clear. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: My problem is solved. But you may add some description, even it is clear in the doc. It is good for everyone.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Also, if I were you I would change the title of the question to something more like _Filtering select field options in django admin_ since it can apply for a more general case. My answer is not only for people using your package. Anyway, it is just a proposition.

Answer (score 1):

limit_choices_to with multiple conditions:

```
staff_member = models.ForeignKey(
User,
on_delete=models.CASCADE,
limit_choices_to={'is_staff': True,is_superuser':False},)
```

we can add multiple limit choices option in the model..

Comment: I have already applied multiple conditions after reading docs. But again, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Limit choice filter with multiple fields with Q object:

```
from django.db.models import Q

limit_to = Q(username="stack") & Q(is_staff=True) & Q(is_active=True)
```